# NullpointerException in onPreExcute of AsyncTask for ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, android-progressbar

I had a **NullPointerException** when I try to set ProgessBar to visible in `onPreExecute AsyncTask (mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);)`. I don't know what went wrong! Thanks you all!

```
 <ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/pb_featured_game_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

... 
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

new FetchGamesTask().execute();


private class FetchGamesTask extends
        AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, List<GameInfo>> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPreExecute();

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pb_featured_game_progress);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Comment: first of all it seems you didn't setContentView in your Activity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you call the execute on your `FetchGamesTask`, you should associate the main view with the xml file.

Like this

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// the OS will inflate the main_activity.xml
// file and use it for this activity
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
new FetchGamesTask().execute();
```

Comment: hi DigCamara, thank you for your reminder! I definitely wrote the setcontentView(R.layout.main_activity) right behind the asynctask! thank you!

Comment: Glad to be helpful. Would you mind marking the question as answered?

Comment: Thank you! Of course, because your answer too soon i couldn't even mark it at that moment!